# A template for Remembering the Kanji?

Tags: book-design

I'm sure some here are familiar with James Heisig's *Remembering the Kanji* book series. The pages are set out as follows:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tofugu.com](https://files.tofugu.com/articles/japanese/2013-05-31-japanese-mnemonics-introduction/heisig-bright.jpg))</sub>
.

I would like to recreate this style (within a `bookest` document) in order to create a guide to chữ Nôm (Vietnamese characters). Does anyone have either a template or a suggested method to recreate this layout which they would be willing to share?

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. What have you done so far? For me, I see one global unit/cell/box per word. This main box is made of several items (the number, the kanji, the english translation, the text/explanation, and the steps of kanji drawing). Try to draw boundaries of their area. Then you can either chose to use an array, or handle boxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can emulate a similar behavior using `mdframed`. What I'm refferring to is the breakable boxes. I'm not sure how stable this is, so test it out...

## MWE

```
\documentclass{bookest}
\usepackage{lipsum,mdframed}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\newcounter{kanji}\setcounter{kanji}{0}
\newlength\kanjisep\setlength{\kanjisep}{2em}
\newenvironment{kanjis}[2]{%
    \stepcounter{kanji}\edef\thesavedkanjicntr{\thekanji}
    \mdfsetup{%
        frametitle={\thesavedkanjicntr\hspace{\kanjisep}#1\hfill #2},
        frametitlebelowskip=\baselineskip,
        subtitlebelowskip=\baselineskip,
        subtitlefont=\LARGE,
        frametitlefont=\LARGE,
        linewidth=1pt,
        innerleftmargin=1cm,
        subtitleaboveline=true}%
    \begin{mdframed}[]\relax}%
    {\end{mdframed}}

\newcommand{\kanji}[2]{%
    \stepcounter{kanji}%
    \mdfsubtitle{\thekanji\hspace{\kanjisep}#1\hfill #2}}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{kanjis}{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}未\end{CJK}}{what's that}
    \lipsum[2]
    \kanji{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}哉\end{CJK}}{something}
    \lipsum[3]
  \end{kanjis}
  \lipsum[4]
  \begin{kanjis}{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}散\end{CJK}}{counter continues}
    \lipsum[5]
    \kanji{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}も\end{CJK}}{so on}
    \lipsum[6]
  \end{kanjis}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*The different line widths of the surrounding box are Viewer artifacts, they should not effect printed copies.

Comment: Maybe if you want to later on `\ref`er to the frames I think you can use `\refstepcounter` instead of the normal `\stepcounter` and `\label` said frames.